# How to put ssl directives in server block instead of http block in nginx configuration?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I am about to use different ssl certificates for different virtual hosts, so I started by moving the existing ssl directives from the `http` block into one of the `server` blocks, before I start to add other ssl certificate directives into other `server` blocks.  But as soon as I did this, the web server involved cannot be accessed anymore.  Chrome reported `connection closed` and Nginx's error log read like this:

```
2016/01/08 20:13:32 [error] 16968#0: *364 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: x.x.x.x, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

The ssl directives I moved include:

```
ssl_certificate
ssl_certificate_key
ssl_protocols
ssl_dhparam
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers
ssl_ciphers
```

What could possibly go wrong when moving these directives from `http` block to `server` block?

Comment: Post your entire server configuration. Also make sure you haven't a global server configured to listen to 443.

Comment: I do have a default server listening on 443, but why does that matter when I'm requesting other servers through their server_name?  And if that one is indeed causing the problem, what ssl_certificate configuration should I put for this default server (because I have more than one ssl certificate for other servers respectively)?

Comment: You can't have a default listening on 443 without providing an SSL certificate. You should disable global listening on 443 if you have no certificate for it.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti: I add one of ssl certificates to the default_server listening on 443 and now everything works fine.  I need to have this default_server to handle any access via unwanted server names (e.g. use IP address directly).  And I'm still not clear about the logic behind this.  The default_server should only be processed when other virtual host listening on 443 is not selected, so why lacking ssl certificates on the default_server could impact access to other virtual hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you haven't a global server configured to listen to 443.

Because you moved the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` within a specific virtual host, that means the default configuration is missing the certificate and key. This is not allowed by Nginx. Each virtual host that is configured to listen on 443, regardless it's the default or not, must be configured to serve a certificate.

> The default_server should only be processed when other virtual host listening on 443 is not selected, so why lacking ssl certificates on the default_server could impact access to other virtual hosts?

That's the point. Nginx reject the configuration because, if this scenario should happen, it would not be able to process the request because of the lacking of the `ssl_certificate`. Therefore, the configuration is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  It seems to me this should be reported as a configuration upon starting nginx, instead of returning error at runtime.  This is the point making me confused.